# How to test PHP cURL file in Postman?

Tags: php, curl, postman

I have a PHP cURL file which works well. I want to test it using postman so that I can implement it in node.js.

Any help on how I can test this RESTful API would be much appreciated:

```php
<?php

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.jaygroup.com/api/mycolabs/inquiry.php",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Accept: */*",
    "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
    "Authorization: Basic dGVzdGluZzppc2Z1bg==",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Connection: keep-alive",
    "Content-Length: 460",
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Cookie: PHPSESSID=m6o4t5382mcdv88qldvj0724ub",
    "Host: api.jaygroup.com",
    "Postman-Token: 51872bbc-d328-4f63-ad0e-f4ef0017871a,a1b5f4f8-e3f9-4f02-88d5-348e2b4e712d",
    "User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.19.0",
    "cache-control: no-cache"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:".$err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Comment: Hello. Please fix your question by indenting the code. This is difficult to read.

Comment: Sorry. but I don't think it is important. I already imported a curl file on the postman.
But it doesn't work properly